# SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: wget, ssl

On my up-to-date 15.04 VV Ubuntu boxes, I tried to download some VMs.

```
wget -c https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE8/Linux/IE8.Win7.For.Linux.VirtualBox.zip
--2015-07-31 09:43:28--  https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE8/Linux/IE8.Win7.For.Linux.VirtualBox.zip
Resolving az412801.vo.msecnd.net (az412801.vo.msecnd.net)... 192.229.145.200, 2606:2800:10c:249:f81:1c8d:1178:1364
Connecting to az412801.vo.msecnd.net (az412801.vo.msecnd.net)|192.229.145.200|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 3985616237 (3.7G), 3971559386 (3.7G) remaining [application/x-zip-compressed]
Saving to: 'IE8.Win7.For.Linux.VirtualBox.zip’

IE8.Win7.For.Linux.   0%[                      ]  14.03M  1.29MB/s   in 0.5s   

2015-07-31 09:43:29 (1.29 MB/s) - Read error at byte 14712199/3985616237 (error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac). Retrying.
```

I also tried without the '-c' (continue) option, but it gets the same error.

In desperation, I've even tried downgrading the SSL security:

```
$wget -c --secure-protocol=SSLv2 https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE8/Linux/IE8.Win7.For.Linux.VirtualBox.zip
--2015-07-31 12:52:17--  https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE8/Linux/IE8.Win7.For.Linux.VirtualBox.zip
OpenSSL: unimplemented 'secure-protocol' option value 1
Please report this issue to bug-wget@gnu.org
Aborted (core dumped)
```

- I've used wget to download from this site before.
- It only seems to be happening on this website.
- Attempts to download from other SSL-enabled sites work.
- Tried different machines, tried mainline kernel, same behaviour.

Is this the first problem a bug in wget, Ubuntu's SSL library, or the server's SSL library and how does one get around it safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It only seems to be happening on this website.

I think it is a bug in the site itself. And it only happens deep inside the connection, i.e. the critical phase of SSL (the initial handshake) is long done. You will probably fail to receive the data using another program or the browser too.

Comment: That's correct, Chrome fails also, but I presumed they were both using the same SSL library.

Comment: @tudor: wget is using OpenSSL while Chrome is using the NSS library for TLS. These are completely different TLS stacks.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This seems to be something more than site specific. Happening to me on dropbox and a host of other sites.

Comment: @horaceT I agree, I've seen it a few times recently.  I'm guessing there's a buggy stack serverside library going around but thankfully it only seems to be a few sites.  Thank goodness for implementation diversity!

Comment: @tudor Do you think this may be a vulnerability in SSL? Is there anyway to report it to the community (other than on SO)?

Comment: @horaceT Generally vulnerabilities are when the operation succeeds and it shouldn't.  However, errors like this can lead to distrust in the software and social engineering attacks.